# Why does this REST-service not return while the other does?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, get

**SITUATION**
In the code below you can see 2 REST services which both should return a MessageVO. The first service (*serviceThatDoesWork*) returns a MessageVO as excpected, but the second service (*serviceThatDoesNotWork*) refuses to, it  doesn't even give any output at all. 
However returning a Response (*java.ws.rs.core.Response*) with serviceThatDoesNotWork does give an output. Even when I skip the 'doStuff'-methods and create a dummy-MessageVO that is exactly the same for each service, the 2nd one doesn't return anything.

**QUESTION**
Why does the 2nd service fail to return a MessageVO? It doens't return anything when I try returning a MessageVO, and nothing out of the ordinary appears in the logging.
The two services need to return exactly the same kind of thing but still one of them doesn't want to return anything, what am I not seeing here?
Could it be because of the path (*and/or the amount of parameters*)?

**CODE**
MyServices.java:

```
@Path("/myService")
...
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/myPath/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")
    public MessageVO serviceThatDoesWork(@PathParam("param1") Integer param1_id,  @PathParam("param2") Integer param2_id, @PathParam("param2") Integer param2_id) 
    {   
        List<SomethingVO> lstO = MyRestServiceBusiness.doStuff(param1_id, param2_id, param3_id);

        //return SUCCESS or FAIL message
        MessageVO msg = new MessageVO();
        if(lstO.size() > 0)
        {
            List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(SomethingVO k : lstO)
            {
                s.add(k.getId().toString());
            }
            msg.setItem_ids(s);
            msg.setMsg("SUCCESS");
        }
        else
        {
            msg.setMsg("FAIL");
        }
        return msg;
    }
...
@GET
@Path("/myPath/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}/{param4}/.../{param15}{a:(/a/[^/]+?)?}{b:(/b/[^/]+?)?}")
public Response serviceThatDoesNotWork(@PathParam("param1")Integer param1_id, ..., @PathParam("param15") Integer param15_id,
            @PathParam("a") String a_id, @PathParam("b") String b_id)
    {       
        //PUT 'OPTIONAL' PARAMS IN A LIST
        List<Integer> lstI = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String aId = a_id != null ? a_id.split("/")[2] : null;
        String bId = b_id != null ? b_id.split("/")[2] : null;
        if(aId != null)
        {
            lstI.add(Integer.parseInt(aId ));
        }
        if(bId  != null)
        {
            lstI.add(Integer.parseInt(bId ));
        }

        //DO STUFF
        String afsId = "";
        if(lstI.size() > 0)
        {
            afsId = MyRestServiceBusiness.doStuff(param1, ..., lstI);
        }

        //return SUCCESS or FAIL message
        MessageVO msg = new MessageVO();
        if(afsId != null && !afsId.isEmpty())
        {
            List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
            s.add(afsId);
            msg.setItem_ids(s);
            msg.setMsg("SUCCESS");
        }
        else
        {
            List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(Integer i : lstI)
            {
                s.add(i.toString());
            }               
            msg.setItem_ids(s);
            msg.setMsg("FAIL");
        }           

        //WENT THROUGH ALL ABOVE CODE AS EXPECTED, MESSAGEVO HAS BEEN FILLED PROPERLY
        return msg; 
    }
```

**CODE** MessageVO.java:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MessageVO 
{   
    private String msg;
    private List<String>  item_ids;


    //GETTERS
    @XmlElement(name = "Message")
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "Item ID's")
    public List<String> getItem_ids() {
        return item_ids;
    }


    //SETTERS
    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    public void setItem_ids(List<String>  item_ids) {
       this.item_ids = item_ids;
    }
```

---

If I need to provide extra information please ask, this is my first attempt at (REST-) services.

Comment: you should use @Produces annotation with serviceThatDoesNotWork method

Comment: @Vaseph oh my, I can't believe I missed that part! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vaseph mentioned in a comment I just forgot the @Produces annotation in the 2nd service.